# Creating values from datetime objects in certain fixed divisions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to create a new column, in which e.g. the time 14:02 should be saved as 14.0, whereas 14:16 should be 14.5. This would equal half-hour units. Of course 15min units should also be creatable and so on. This is my approach for full hours, but I need a higher resolution.

`df["Time"] = df.StartDateTime.apply(lambda x: x.hour)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as the units evenly divide an hour you can `round` with that frequency and then divide by an hour.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': pd.timedelta_range('14:00:00', freq='4min', periods=10)})

for freq in ['30min', '15min', '20min', '10min']:
    df[freq] = df['Time'].dt.round(freq)/pd.Timedelta('1H')
```

---

```
      Time  30min  15min      20min      10min
0 14:00:00   14.0  14.00  14.000000  14.000000
1 14:04:00   14.0  14.00  14.000000  14.000000
2 14:08:00   14.0  14.25  14.000000  14.166667
3 14:12:00   14.0  14.25  14.333333  14.166667
4 14:16:00   14.5  14.25  14.333333  14.333333
5 14:20:00   14.5  14.25  14.333333  14.333333
6 14:24:00   14.5  14.50  14.333333  14.333333
7 14:28:00   14.5  14.50  14.333333  14.500000
8 14:32:00   14.5  14.50  14.666667  14.500000
9 14:36:00   14.5  14.50  14.666667  14.666667
```

---

If you start from a `datetime64[ns]` column you can isolate the time by subtracting off the normalized date. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': pd.date_range('2010-01-01 14:00:00', freq='4min', periods=5)})
df['Time_only'] = df['Time'] - df['Time'].dt.normalize()
#                 Time Time_only
#0 2010-01-01 14:00:00  14:00:00
#1 2010-01-01 14:04:00  14:04:00
#2 2010-01-01 14:08:00  14:08:00
#3 2010-01-01 14:12:00  14:12:00
#4 2010-01-01 14:16:00  14:16:00

print(df.dtypes)
#Time          datetime64[ns]
#Time_only    timedelta64[ns]
#dtype: object
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try to execute it: TypeError: cannot perform __truediv__ with this index type: DatetimeArray. The column "Time" is of the type datetime64[ns].

Comment: @leabum In that case first do something like `df['Time_only'] = df['Time'] - df['Time'].dt.normalize()` This subtracts the date and will give you a `timedelta64[ns]` column for the time in the day